# Ajax Call not being passed, POST.request shows as None

Tags: java, ajax, django, django-views

I am having issues getting my POST request to capture the selected check boxes.  It's been suggested to me to use Ajax so I did with the following:

```
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
                      var SelectedItems = [];
                      $('.checkbox').click(function () {
                          var SelectedItems = $(this).val();
                          var index = SelectedItems.indexOf(SelectedItems);
                          var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                          if (index == -1)
                          {
                            SelectedItems.push(SelectedItems);
                          }        else {
                            SelectedItems.splice(index, 1);
                          }
                        });

                      $('#submit-button').click(function (event) {
                          event.preventDefault();
                          $.ajax({
                              url: "{% url 'requestaccess' %}",
                              data: JSON.stringify({ report_id: SelectedItems }),
                              dataType: 'json',
                              type: 'POST',
                              success: function (data) {
                              },
                            });
                        });
                    });
                  </script>
```

When I push the button my chrome developer Network tab only shows the jquery.min being the initiator.  However, when I print my request.POST call as a get or getlist on the request access view it displays either an emptylist or NONE, my web application isn't switching from /account/profile to /account/requestaccess on the button press:

```
[15/Nov/2017 15:04:02] "POST /account/requestaccess/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1031
None
[]
[15/Nov/2017 15:04:43] "POST /account/requestaccess/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1031
```

My view for requestaccess is the following:

```
@csrf_exempt
def requestaccess(request):
    import simplejson as json
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername, active = 1).values('report_name_sc')
    reportIds = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values_list('report_id', flat=True)
    reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).exclude(active=0)
    checkedlist = request.POST.getlist('report_id')
    checked = request.POST.get('report_id')
#    checkboxvalue = request.POST['request_reports']
    if request.method == 'POST':

        print (checked)
        print (checkedlist)


    args = {'retreivecheckbox': checkedlist}

    return render(request,'accounts/requestaccess.html')
```

Any idea as to why report_id is not being passed to requestaccess with the checkbox values of report_id?  If i change my POST to a get I can see the values being passed in the current view and my url changes to /accounts/requestaccess.html.

Comment: Why would you expect the URL to change? And why would you expect the form parameter `report_id` to give anything when you're not sending form-encoded data?

Comment: I thought since i'm sending the post request to accounts/requestaccess the URL would change based on the HREF = "{% url 'requestaccess' %} on the button.  How would I send report_id as form-encoded data, i thought having my check boxes between <form action "">  would work perhap's i'm missing something.

Comment: No. The whole point of Ajax is that neither of these things happen. If you want to change the URL on submit, and send form data, then *don't use Ajax*. I don't see why you need to anyway, for a simple list of checkboxes.

Comment: It was suggested to me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243321/pass-multiple-checkbox-selections-in-a-template-to-a-form  I'm very new to this type of development and I don't really have a mentor.  How would I get all my check boxes a user selects in one view passed to another without using a request.POST.get/getlist?

Comment: You *would* use `getlist`. That is exactly what it is for: getting the data from a list of check boxes.

Comment: After removing the Ajax and Jquery scripts, when using checkedlist = request.GET.getlist('report_id') it doesn't print a value on requestaccess using print (checkedlist)

Comment: i can help with the AJAX call, but do nto want to aruge with its merits.

Comment: i can help with the AJAX call, but do not want to argue the merits. As it stands there are nothing in the success block, so it won't do anything. Here is what I would suggest: Add  a console.log statement to the success block: console.log('success: ' + serverResponse_data) to see what the call is returning, then you can debug further from there.